# Oracle 12c - Invalid username/password for ctxsys after password change

Tags: oracle-12c, sqlplus

I am running an SQL script which starts with these commands:

```sql
connect sys/intershop as sysdba

ALTER user ctxsys account unlock;
ALTER user ctxsys identified by ctxsys;

-- Grants with Grant Option for CTXSYS User and Lock CTXSYS Again
connect ctxsys/ctxsys;

GRANT EXECUTE ON CTX_DDL TO sys    WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT EXECUTE ON CTX_DDL TO system WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The problem is that `connect ctxsys/ctxsys` returns an error due to invalid credentials, even though they were successfully updated by the above `ALTER user ctxsys identified by ctxsys`!

```
sh-4.2$ sqlplus -s /nolog
connect sys/intershop as sysdba
ALTER user ctxsys account unlock;

User altered.

ALTER user ctxsys identified by ctxsys;

User altered. // <----- ctxsys user's password should have been successfully updated

connect ctxsys/ctxsys;
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
GRANT EXECUTE ON CTX_DDL TO sys    WITH GRANT OPTION;
SP2-0640: Not connected
GRANT EXECUTE ON CTX_DDL TO system WITH GRANT OPTION;
SP2-0640: Not connected
```

My version of Oracle is 12.2.0.1.0 Standard Edition. I have installed it with Docker, using the [Dockerfile provided by Oracle](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile).

The script I am trying to execute is a custom script to initialize a database on my local development environment.